# Using SCP in a Bastion VM setup with an established SSH tunnel

Tags: centos, scp, ssh-tunneling, google-cloud

I am looking at ways to mitigate the potential for using scp commands within GCE VMs that are running CentOS 8.

Current setup is a bastion VM being able to SSH into a secondary VM (instance-1). I have not been able to SSH back from the secondary VM into the bastion VM after establishing the first SSH connection and I am assuming this is due to not having a SSH keypair in the opposite direction (someone correct me if I am wrong there). Error when running `ssh <BASTION_IP>` is `Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)`

I am attempting to SCP from instance-1 to the bastion and that does not work either with an error of `Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)`. This is due to the SSH keypair not being present correct?

Is there a way to work around this? I want to see what potential approaches can be used for running SCP commands from instance-1 to the bastion. Would any form of TCP forwarding or establishing a different SSH tunnel allow for files to be transferred out

**Edit for additional details.**

Instance-1 only has a private IP. Both VMs are in two separate GCP projects with a VPC peering between networks.

No NAT gateway or other proxies to allow instance-1 to have external internet access.

Bastion does not have a public key for a private key in instance-1

**Edit for additional questions.**

With the bastion establishing an SSH tunnel to instance-1 is there anyway to be in instance-1 and somehow get a file out of instance-1 to the Bastion?

Does SCP not work if there is not a public key from instance-1's SSH keypair on the Bastion?

Comment: 1) Does **instance-1** have Internet access or does it only have a private IP address? Does your VPC have a NAT Gateway or other proxy? Those would allow **instance-1** to access the Internet directly. 2) Unless the **Bastion** has the public key for the private key that **instance-1** is using, you will not be able to connect to the bastion host. I am not sure what you mean by workaround - the systems are either secure or they are not.

Comment: 1) Instance-1 only has a private IP. Both VMs are in two separate GCP projects with a VPC peering between networks. 2) No NAT gateway or other proxies to allow instance-1 to have external internet access. 3) Bastion does not have a public key for a private key in instance-1. 4) So even with the bastion establishing an SSH tunnel to instance-1 is there anyway to be in instance-1 and somehow get a file out of instance-1 to the Bastion? 5). SCP does not work in this case due to the Bastion not having the public key from the private key that would be located in instance-1, if there was one?

Comment: Please edit your question with those details. The user can log in to the Bastion host and create a reverse SSH tunnel. The user can log in to instance-1 and connect back to that tunnel without SSH keys which would allow Internet access.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest sftp command. First connect to Bastion Server via normal SSH.  From the Bastion server, start an SFTP session

```
$ sftp -i /PATH/TO/SSH/KEY user@remote-vm-ip
```

Once you are inside, you can move around the file system using `cd` command (`cd` for remote while `lcd` for local)
Use the `ls` command to list files (`ls` for remote while `lcd` for local)
Want to download a file, simply use `get` command (`get file.txt`for example)
Want to upload files, simply use `put` command (`put file.txt` for example)

You can also automate the process with `sftp` or `scp` commands, as long you have access from one machine to the other, and also know where the source file is located on the filesystem.

Reference:

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/using-sftp-script-rsa-authentication

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/sftp-1.html